# Calling filter with a variable for field name

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there a way to call filter on a queryset where one of the fieldnames is a variable?

For example I have something like:

**`models.py`**

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    video = ...
```

**`views.py`**

```
field_name = 'video'
Playlist.objects.filter(field_name=v)
```

Which of course results in an error that `field_name` is not an attribute upon which `Playlist` can be filtered.

Comment: Common, I need Internet points!

Answer (score 87):

`Playlist.objects.filter(**{field_name: v})`

Comment: how do i use __icontains with the field_name? it gives an error

Comment: Try with: field_name = 'video__icontains' , it worked for me

Answer (score 10):

To use field name string with `icontains`.

Try this

```
field_name = 'video'
field_name_icontains = field_name + '__icontains'
Playlist.objects.filter(**{field_name_icontains: v})
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the model name as a **variable** in a queryset? eg. in a queryset like `var_duty_cond = DutyHdr.objects.get(duty_hdr_component = varMainDutyType).duty_main`, how may I pass a variable `varDutyHdr` in place of **model** `DutyHdr`?