# django pass field-name as variable in get_or_create

Tags: python, django

I am trying to see if I can pass field name as a variable in get_or_create (since I have a function where the key in the kwargs can vary)

Like so:

```
def convert_value(cell_value, field_to_lookup):
        rem_obj, created = Rem.objects.get_or_create(field_to_lookup=cell_value)
        print ('created? ',created)
        return rem_obj
```

The above wont work since it would look for 'field_to_lookup' as the key.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464080/django-model-field-by-variable) post suggests using getattr but not sure if that'll be applicable in this case since I will again need to assign the output to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122169/calling-filter-with-a-variable-for-field-name) post helped. Now passing the field-value pair as dict which allows passing variables for field names. Here's the code:

```
def convert_value(cell_value, field_to_lookup):
        rem_obj, created = Rem.objects.get_or_create(**{field_to_lookup:cell_value})
        print ('created? ',created)
        return rem_obj
```

Alternatively, I could directly just pass the dict to the function.

Comment: Nope, that's the obvious canonical solution.