# Using variable instead of field name in Django query comparions

Tags: django

Let say I have the following query:

```
query_result = Mymodel.objects.values('price').filter(price__gte=0)
```

If I want to generalize the query and put it in a function I could replace `'price'` with a variable:

```
def price_query(column_name):
    query_result = Mymodel.objects.values(column_name).filter(column_name__gte=0)
    return query_result 

price_query('price')
```

The first replacement of `'price'` with `column_name` works fine but how do I use the comparison `__gte` with a variable instead of the field name.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can unpack dictionary to provide keyword arguments:

```
def price_query(column_name):
    filter_kwargs = {
        "{}__gte".format(column_name): 0
    }
    query_result = Mymodel.objects.values(column_name).filter(**filter_kwargs)
return query_result
```

Answer (score -1):

Long story short, you cannot do this.

Querysets are limited to model fields, which are the column names as you said. In fact, they operate only in database-layer, where your variables are not existent.

You will have to follow another filtering approach in order to include variables.

Comment: It's totally doable right from the filter if you use kwargs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122180/5892606